# usage of regular expression in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, expression

I try to parse strings using regular expression by this pattern

> text1 (text2 500g OR kg text3) text4

***example***

```
1.tomato (more 500g)
2.potatoes (1 kg) 
3.potatoes (10 kg) onion
```

How i can using re extract text1+text4

> ```
> 1. tomato
> 2. potatoes
> 3. potatoes onion
> ```

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to line up with what you're asking - you've noted you want text1 & text2, but your example #3 displays text1 & text4.  Considering making this question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer below just matches the text and extracts the subtexts using groups

The data:

```
strings = ["1.tomato (more 500g)",
"2.potatoes (1 kg)", 
"3.potatoes (10 kg) onion", 
"4.potatoes (10 abc) onion"]
```

Write a convenience function:

```
def find_substrings(s):
    #remove spaces for convenience
    s = re.sub(" ", "", s)

    #the regular expression
    match = re.search("([\w\.]+)\([\w]+[kg]\)([\w]+)?", s)

    #what to return when there is a match
    if match:
        return(" ".join([x for x in match.groups() if x]))
```

This yields the result:

```
In [6]: [find_substrings(x) for x in strings]
Out[6]: ['1.tomato', '2.potatoes', '3.potatoes onion', None]
```

Comment: Thank you. it works, but expression must not match when inside () is no kg or g. Example "4.potatoes (10 abc) onion" - no match

Comment: @AlexanderVedmed', make sure to include these types of restrictions in your questions ;) I added that condition into the above regular expression.